# How to create a pandas dataframe where columns are filled with random strings?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a Pandas dataframe with 2 columns and x number rows that contain random strings.

I have found code to generate a pandas dataframe with random ints and a random stringer generator. I still don't see a clear path to create a pandas data frame with random strings.

Code for random int dataframe

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
```

Code for random strings

```py
import string
import random
def id_generator(size=1500, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))

id_generator()
```

I would like destiredDataframe.head() to output two columns of random text and x number of rows.

Comment: Change `size=(100,4)` to `size=(100,2)` and `columns = list('AB')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
num_rows = 10

data = np.array([id_generator() for i in range(2*num_rows)]).reshape(-1,2)
pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can populate the entire column with random available values(strings) with the following steps —

For Example: If you wanna populate the `Gender` column randomly with `male` and `female` you can do this by the below snippet.

```
gender_series = df.gender.apply(lambda x: random.choice(['male', 'female']) )
```

Now you have to add this series in the original dataframe by this code —

```
df['gender'] = gender_series
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do something like below:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(4,3)).applymap(lambda x: np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_letters)))
   0  1  2
0  w  c  c
1  o  B  I
2  n  T  q
3  l  X  K
```