# Fastest/most computationally efficient way to create a pandas dataframe where columns are filled with random strings, for several million rows?

Tags: python, pandas

This is a followup to this question

[How to create a pandas dataframe where columns are filled with random strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56398568/how-to-create-a-pandas-dataframe-where-columns-are-filled-with-random-strings)

In which an solution is given to full pandas rows with random strings. However, the solution is not fast enough for me, as it takes many hours to create several million rows of data, which I need to create a minimal example for another problem involving memory error.

I have tried the following code

```py
from random import randint
import string
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random
draw = randint(200, 5500)
def id_generator(size=draw, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))

num_rows =10000
data = np.array([id_generator() for i in range(2*num_rows)]).reshape(-1,2)
dfAll = pd.DataFrame(data)

#original is 65
for i in range(300):
    print('step ', i)
    draw = randint(200, 5500)
    data = np.array([id_generator() for i in range(2*num_rows)]).reshape(-1,2)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    dfAll = pd.concat([ df,  dfAll ])
```

I am making the dataframe using the append method with chunks otherwise there will be a memory error if I do it all at once.

I am using Google Collaboratory as my enviroment. My desired result is that it makes a 6 million row dataframe of random string within 1 hour. For this, I need a more computationally efficient method of populating a pandas dataframe with random strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use NumPy to generate the array of strings with a single call to `np.random.choice`,
instead of a list comprehension which calls `id_generator` `2*num_rows` times (and calls `random.choice` `2*num_rows*size` times):

```
import string
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from random import randint
import random

def make_random_str_array(size=10, num_rows=100, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
    return (np.random.choice(list(chars), num_rows*size)
            .view('|U{}'.format(size)))

def id_generator(size, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))

def orig(size, num_rows):
    data = np.array([id_generator(size=size) for i in range(2*num_rows)]).reshape(-1, 2)
    dfAll = pd.DataFrame(data)
    return dfAll

def alt(size, num_rows):
    data = make_random_str_array(size, num_rows=2*num_rows).reshape(-1, 2)
    dfAll = pd.DataFrame(data)
    return dfAll
```

---

For `size=1000` and `num_rows=10000`, `alt` is ~26x faster:

```
In [94]: %timeit orig(1000, 10000)
9.22 s ± 49.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [95]: %timeit alt(1000, 10000)
343 ms ± 2.85 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [97]: 9220/343
Out[98]: 26.88046647230321
```

---

Note that calling `pd.concat` in a for-loop leads to [quadratic copying](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36489724/190597).
It is much more efficient to collect the sub-DataFrames in a list, and then call `pd.concat` *once* after the loop has completed:

```
parts = []
for i in range(300):
    print('step ', i)
    size = random.randint(200, 5500)
    data = make_random_str_array(size, num_rows=2*num_rows).reshape(-1, 2)
    parts.append(pd.DataFrame(data))
dfAll = pd.concat(parts)
```